# A Question of Hilbert's Theorem(from Do Carmo)

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

From 'Do Carmo Differential Geometry of curves and surfaces'.

There are 8 lemmas prepared to prove Hilbert's Theorem 5.11:

> There is no complete surface with negative constant curvature which can be isometrically immersed in to $\mathbb{E}^3$.

I don't know the usage of Lemma 7 when proving Hilbert's Theorem, Lemma 7 is stated as:

> On $S'$ there are two differentiable linearly independent vector fields which are tangent to the asymptotic curves of $S'$.

I want to know how Lemma 7 is applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lemma 7 is applied in Lemma 8, where it is proven that $\mathbf{x}\colon R^3\to S'$ is injective.

More specifically, in the beginning of the proof they assume that $\mathbf{x}(s_0,t_0) = \mathbf{x}(s_1,t_0)$, $s_1 > s_0$, which means that the asymptotic line $s\mapsto \mathbf{x}(s,t_0)$ intersects itself. By Lemma 7 the asymptotic line cannot intersect itself unless the tangent lines agree at the intersection point.

Comment: maybe i should have asked the question in this way:why lemma7 implies that the asymptotic line cannot intersect itself unless the tangent lines agree at the intersection point

Comment: If the asymptotic line intersects itself such that the tangent lines do not agree at the intersection point, then there are four (linearly independent) asymptotic direction in that point. This is a contradiction to Lemma 7, which states there are only two asymptotic directions.

Comment: I think now I know why.Suppose $q=x(s_0,t_0)=x(s_1,t_1)$ and the tangent lines of $x(s,t_0)$ don't agree at $q$.Choose an arc joining  $p$ and $x(s_0,t_0)$ and choose another arc joining $p$ and $x(s_1,t_0)$,and then the second vector field $v_2$ satisfies that $v_2(x(s_0,t_0))\not=v_2(x(s_1,t_0))$,which is a contradiction to that the definition of $v_2$ doesn't depend on the choice of the arc joining $p$ and $q$.